# How to plot a Sum function with Bessel function of the first kind

Tags: plotting, functions, summation

I have looked around for a code that can help to plot the magnitude and phase of the following sum

```
Sum[(BesselJ[n, r] e^(I n ϕ))/I^n, {n, -N, N}]
```

But I am not able to find an example. I would like to plot this for various levels of n. Any help very appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: `Sum[BesselJ[n, r] Sin[I* n *\[Phi]]/I^n, {n, -k, k}]` performs `0`.

Comment: `N` has a built-in meaning and should not be used as a user-defined variable/constant. `Sin[I n \[Phi]]` is the proper syntax and spelling; however, the sum is zero so the plot won't be very interesting.

Comment: @BobHanlon  See changes in the formula

Comment: `e` should be `E` (all built - in names start with a capital letter) . Use `Plot3D` to plot against both `r` and `phi` for a given number of terms.

Comment: And as advised earlier, don't use `N`.

Comment: @BobHanlon does this seem reasonable start? Plot3d[Sum[(BesselJ[n, r] E^(I n ϕ)) I^n, {1, -5, 5}, {ϕ, -10, 10}, {r, -2pi, 2pi}] ? I am not sure on how to use the  {n, -N, N} part. The rest is more familiar, except the Sum form for the given function.

Comment: Use the documentation. `Plot3D` and `Pi` are misspelled. There are syntax errors. You cannot plot a complex function with `Plot3D`, use `Abs` or `Arg` of the function to obtain a real-valued function. The range of `r` and `phi` appear to be interchanged.

Comment: @BobHanlon  Thanks, will try and get back!

Comment: @BobHanlon I try the method by Ymir, but I forgot to add that I need to define the domain for r and phi. If I define this for the function u[r_, \[Phi]_ ] := 
 Sum[(BesselJ[n, r]* E^(I n \[Phi])) I^n, {r, 0, 4}, {\[Phi], 0, 
   2 \[Pi]}, {n, -nf, nf}], then I can't plot it with his method. Any idea how to include the domain and plot this? I tried your Arg and Abs, but they give some constants, for specific values of N within a define domain.

Comment: To plot the magnitude: `Clear["Global\`*"]; f[r_, phi_, k_] := Sum[(BesselJ[n, r] E^(I n phi))/I^n, {n, -k, k}]; Plot3D[Abs[f[r, phi, 7]], {r, -10, 10}, {phi, -Pi, Pi}, PlotPoints -> 75, ClippingStyle -> None]` To plot the phase, replace `Abs` with `Arg`

Answer (score 1):

As already been advised in the comments:

1. Don't use `N` - it is reserved.
2. Use `E` instead of `e`. `e` is just a parameter.

There are 2 functions that can help you: ComplexPlot,ComplexPlot3D. You can read about them [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ComplexVisualization.html). I will provide you an example:

```
nf = 4; (*Final n*)
f1[r_, \[Phi]_] :=
  Sum[(BesselJ[n, r]*E^(I n \[Phi]))/I^n, {n, -nf, nf}];
(*Changing to singal variable representation *)
f2[z_] := f1[Abs[z], Arg[z]];
ComplexPlot[f2[z], {z, -1 - I, 1 + I}] 
ComplexPlot3D[f2[z], {z, -1 - I, 1 + I}]
```

The output:
[image: Color -Phase]
[image: Color - Phase, Height - Manititude]

You can also read about the [Manipulate](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html?q=Manipulate) option to write a code where you change `nf` with a dynamic slide. Generally, if you want to show several graphics combined you would use the [Show](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html?q=Show) function, but as you use the color of the graph to represent the phase, I would not advise doing so. Plot for every `n` separately.

Hope that helps

Comment: Many thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I tried your suggestion with Manipulate. Does the command fit in at the end? (*Final n*)
u[r_, \[Phi]_] := 
  Sum[(BesselJ[n, r]*E^(I n \[Phi])) I^n, {n, -nf, nf}];
(*Changing to single variable representation*)
u1[z_] := u[Abs[z], Arg[z]];
ComplexPlot[u1[z], {z, -1 - I, 1 + I}]
Manipulate[u1[z], {nf, {1, 2, 3, 5}}]  ?

Comment: @user287546 You will have to use Plot inside manipulate: Manipulate[Plot[u1[z],{z,0,1}],{nf,1,2,3,5}]. Please read more about Manipulate.

Comment: Ok, thank you for this

Comment: Hi @Ymir, I tried to extent your code to a certain defined domain of phi and r. But this works only for complexplot and not for complexplot3D. Are there limitations of Complexplot3d for this case? nf = 5;(*Final n*)[u[r_, \[Phi]_] := 
  Sum[(BesselJ[n, r]*E^(I n \[Phi])) I^n, {n, -nf, nf}], {r, 0, 
  4}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}];
(*Changing to single variable representation*)
u1[z_] := u[Abs[z], Arg[z]]; ComplexRegionPlot[
 Abs[u1[z]] <= 1 && Abs[Arg[u1[z]]] > \[Pi]/4, {z, -1 - I, 1 + I}, 
 PlotStyle -> Orange]

Comment: This solution grants for further investigation, on how to define the boundary of r and phi, which is not evident at all.