# Using Manipulate with a Bessel function for specific levels N of the sum

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I try to plot an interactive plot where one can select the levels of N (noted nf) for a Bessel function:

```
nf = 8;
u[r_, ϕ_] := Nsum[(BesselJ[n, r]*E^(I n ϕ)) I^n, {n, -nf, nf}];

(*Changing to single variable representation*)
u1[z_] := u[Abs[z], Arg[z]];
Manipulate[Plot[u1[z], {z, 0, 1}], {n, 1, 2, 3, 5}]
```

But I get nothing...
Any suggestion on how to use Manipulate to show levels of N (nf) from 1 to 8 for instance?

Thank you

Comment: Use `NSum` and make sure `nf` is defined.

Answer (score 1):

I present here a contiution to the solution for [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/244591/how-to-plot-a-sum-function-with-bessel-function-of-the-first-kind/244626?noredirect=1#comment615824_244626). This is the solution:

```
nf = 8;
u[r_, \[Phi]_, nf_] := 
  Sum[(BesselJ[n, r]*E^(I n \[Phi]))/I^n, {n, -nf, nf}];

(*Changing to single variable representation*)
u1[z_, n_] := u[Abs[z], Arg[z], n];

a = Manipulate[
  ComplexPlot3D[u1[z, n], {z, -1 - I, 1 + I}], {n, 1, nf, 1}]
CloudDeploy[a]
```

Note that you should use here ComplexPlot3D, and when you use `Manipulate` you must give it access to a variable that you change dynamically - n.

Comment: Thank you Ymir. I noticed the increase of levels of N gives a very long computation time, and the plots are very different.  Would not the highest value of n give the most accurate results?

Comment: @user287546 I'm not familiar with this specific sum. It depends on whether the sum converges or diverges. Even if it does converge, it can go crazy for small n, and strat to converge at some large n. So for you question: long computation time is excepted, and more accurate results depend on the mathematics.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for this. Do you have other scripts at the cloud which you recommend for analysing such complex sums?

Comment: @user287546 Maybe you should read the Complex Vizualiztion guide on the Mathematica reference website. Hope that you will find something useful over there.

Comment: Thanks, will do!